# Parseing XML PHP 4.3.0+

Tags: php

I am trying to determine whether the function domxml_open_mem and xpath_new_context is available under version PHP V4.3.0 or not.  I am using IIS7 under windows 7.

I am reading the document from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.domxml-open-mem.php
it seemed like the the those functions are available these version.

I've tried to test this under multiple PHP versions from 4.1.2 to 4.3.0 and the results are those function are not available.

```
if (function_exists('domxml_open_mem')) {
    echo "Function is available.<br />\n";
} else {
    echo " Function is not available.<br />\n";
}
```

Any ideas?
My goal is to parse the value from the xml from the string below

```
$xml_String="<xml><Fields><Header>aa</Header><Header>bb</Header></Fields></xml>";
```

and display back

//The code need to be compatible from 4.3.0 to the latest versions.

```
$xpresult = xpath_eval($xml_String, "/xml/Fields/Header");
foreach ($xpresult->nodeset as $node)
{
    $newxml .= $node->dump_node($node);
}
```

Comment: Why bother? All versions of PHP 4.x are unsupported nowadays, and most of them also have serious known security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Windows 7 was released in late **2009**, PHP 5.0.0 was released in middle of **2004**. How comes your "server" has PHP 4.3 ( last version of which was released in early 2005 ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it hasn't been compiled into your version of PHP:

> In PHP 4 this PECL extensions source can be found in the `ext/` directory within the PHP source or at the PECL link above. **This extension is only available if PHP was configured with `--with-dom[=DIR]`.** Add `--with-dom-xslt[=DIR]` to include DOM XSLT support. `DIR` is the libxslt install directory. Add `--with-dom-exslt[=DIR]` to include DOM EXSLT support, where `DIR` is the libexslt install directory.
>
> http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxml.installation.php

Comment: i guess i have to enable this somehow

Comment: @James That pretty much means you have to recompile PHP. At which point you may as well upgrade to 5.3... :)